# Tic-tac-toe game; JavaScript; the code is written but does not work

Tags: javascript, arrays, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to create a 'tic-tac-toe' game on **JavaScript**. This is actually my homework, however my teacher refuses to give me any feedback, even though I am completely stuck. Anyway, my task is to make up the logic of the game, the action listeners are already given by the task. I did the researh and I've wrote the code, but the game does not work properly, namely, the program does not check, whether there has been a win and does not display who was the winner. Also, it does not check if there was a draw. Here is my code, that I need help with:

```
let players = ['x', 'o'];
let activePlayer = 0;

const winningCombos = [
  ['0', '0', '1', '1', '2', '2'],
  ['0', '2', '1', '1', '2', '0'],
  ['0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '2'],
  ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '2'],
  ['2', '0', '2', '1', '2', '2'],
  ['0', '0', '1', '0', '2', '0'],
  ['0', '1', '1', '1', '2', '1'],
  ['0', '2', '1', '2', '2', '2'],
]

let board = [
  ['', '', ''],
  ['', '', ''],
  ['', '', '']
];

function switchPlayer() {
  if (activePlayer == players[0]) {
    activePlayer = players[1]
  } else if (activePlayer == players[1]) {
    activePlayer = players[0]
  } else {
    console.log('Error')
  }
}

function startGame() {
  activePlayer = players[Math.floor(players.length * Math.random())]; // Random selection of the first active player
  alert ('Active player is: ' + activePlayer);
  renderBoard(board);
}

let oResult = []; // an Arry for storing the rows and columns of the 'o' 
let xResult = []; // an Arry for storing the rows and columns of the 'x' 


//This is the function that is supposed to check whether there is a draw, but does not do that. My idea was that it should check, if the 'oResult' and the 'xResult' arrays have reached their maximum (so they are completely filled) and if yes, they should display into the console the phrae "it's a draw"
function ifDraw() {
  if (((oResult.length === 7) && (xResult.length === 9)) || ((oResult.length === 9) && (xResult.length === 7))) {
    console.log('its a draw')
  } 
}
//This function does not work as well, if I understand correctly. I thought, that the FOR cycle would go through each array in the 'winningCombos' array and compare it with the oResult and the 'xResult' arrays. When one of these two arrays matches one of the arrays from 'winningCombos', then the function 'showWinner' is called (the 'showWinner' function is already given by the task)
function ifWon() {
  for (let i = 0; i < winningCombos.length; i++) {
    if ((oResult === winningCombos[i]) || (xResult === winningCombos[i])) {
      showWinner(activePlayer)
    } 
  }
}

function click(row, column) {
  board[row][column] = activePlayer;
  switchPlayer();
  renderBoard(board);

  //Even though it was stated clearly, that the values of 'x' have to be written into the 'xResult' and the values of 'o' - into the 'oResult', the program sometimes mixes it up and the values of 'x' sometimes go to the 'oResult'. Why?
  if (activePlayer === 'x') {
    xResult.push(row);
    xResult.push(column);
  } else if (activePlayer === 'o') {
    oResult.push(row);
    oResult.push(column);
  }

  //These don't work
  ifDraw();
  ifWon();

  // Here I display what has been assignet to what in the console so that I can check the process
  console.log(xResult)
  console.log(oResult)
  console.log('-')
}
```

The problem is that to me the code makes sense. My teacher also didn't point out any major mistakes. However, I can't find the reason why doesn't the game show who has won, or even stop at ay point.
The code below is **not necessary** to read, because it is simply the given task and if you want to see how the game looks like live.

Here is what has been given by the task (also **JS**, is in another file):

```
window.addEventListener('load', startGame);

let boardEl = document.getElementById('board');
let modalEl = document.getElementById('modal');
let resetButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('reset');

for (let btn of resetButtons) {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!modalEl.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      modalEl.classList.add('hidden');
    }
    startGame();
  });
}

boardEl.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  let targetClasses = event.target.classList;
  let targetData = event.target.dataset;
  if (targetClasses.contains('field') && !targetClasses.contains('busy')) {
    click(targetData.row, targetData.col);
  }
});

function showWinner(winner) {
  let header = modalEl.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
  header.textContent = ` Won the player №${winner + 1}! `;
  modalEl.classList.remove('hidden');
}

function renderBoard(board) {
  const fields = [];
  for (let [i, row] of board.entries()) {
    for (let [j, value] of row.entries()) {
      fields.push(`
        <div class="field ${value ? 'busy' : 'free'}" 
            data-row="${i}" 
            data-col="${j}"
            style="grid-row:${i + 1};grid-column:${j + 1};"
        >
          ${value || ''}
        </div>
      `);
    }
  }
  boardEl.innerHTML = fields.join('');
}
```

Below are the HTML and CSS files that make up the looks (were also given by the task). If you would like to see what I see, I use the Repl.it platform to do my writings. 
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Tic-tac-toe</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="board"></div>

<div id="modal" class="hidden">
    <div id="modal__window">
        <h2></h2>
        <div id="modal__buttons">
            <button class="reset">Play again</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
    <button class="reset">From the beginning</button>
</div>

<script src="logic.js"></script>
<script src="ui.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.panel {
    text-align: center;
}



#board {
    position: relative;
    height: 450px;
    width: 450px;
    margin: 50px auto 30px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
    grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
    grid-gap: 10px;
}

.field {
    background-color: #78bec5;
    border-radius: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 5em;
    font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
}

.free:hover {
    background-color: #3d4250;
}

#modal {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#modal__window {
    position: relative;
    top: 30%;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 20px 20px;
    background-color: #f8f6f6;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    min-width: 100px;
    border: 1px solid lightgray;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 20pt;
    border-radius: 15px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

button:hover {
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 0 rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

button:active {
    box-shadow: inset 2px 1px 0;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

I would really appreciate any help or directions, I don't know what am I doing wrong and where are the mistakes. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey Sasha, welcome to the site! It's time consuming for anyone to dig deep into your question when it's posed like that. You didn't say what the actual issue is (are there any console errors? is the game playing until some point and then stops? does the page load at all?) and you pasted so much code that no one will be really inclined to read it all.

Try narrowing the issue down yourself at least a bit. Otherwise it *kinda* looks like you want someone to do your homework. I suspect that's the reason your teacher refused to give you immediate feedback.

Comment: I simply want a push to the right direction, because I don't know what to do. I've written the code that makes sense, I just don't know why doesn't it work

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your functions that check for outcomes of the game, like `ifWon` and `ifDraw` are trying to check array equality using `===`. This will not work, since checking equality of arrays requires checking whether every element in one array matches its corresponding element (i.e., the element at the same index) in the second array. One quick way to test array equality is using `JSON.stringify`:

```
if (JSON.stringify(arr1) === JSON.stringify(arr2)) {...your code here}
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for advise, good to know. However, I've added this: 
if ((JSON.stringify(oResult) === SON.stringify(winningCombos)) || (JSON.stringify(xResult) === JSON.stringify(winningCombos)))
but it doesn't do anything anyway. Do you think I call the function in a wrong way somehow?